# Storing translation array in cookie

Tags: php

I save translation text in PHP files like that:

en.php:

```
$translation = [
    "home" => [
        "title" => "Home",
    ],
    "contact" => [
        "title" => "Contact", 
    ],
];

return json_encode($translation);
```

I want to save this array in cookie to use it across the website without including it each time the user visits a page.

So in header.php:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['translation']) && !isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $translation = require_once('en.php');
    setcookie('translation', $translation, time()+86400, '/');
    $_COOKIE['translation'] = $translation;
}elseif(isset($_GET['lang'])){
    $translation = require_once($_GET['lang'] . '.php');
    setcookie('translation', $translation, time()+86400, '/');
    $_COOKIE['translation'] = $translation;
}

$decode = json_decode($_COOKIE['translation']);

echo $decode->home->title;
```

But I'm getting an error `This site can’t be reached ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`

Comment: `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` usually means something is corrupting the compression. If you exit on the first line do you still get the invalid response? If not can add more details about how you are exporting content, are you compressing (gzip) the data for return?

Comment: You might also want to look at assigning that `require` to a variable. See `Handling Returns` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Remove `return json_encode($translation);` in en.php

Then in header.php :

```
if (! isset($_COOKIE['translation']) && ! isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  require_once('en.php');
  $jsonEncodedTranslation = json_encode($translation);

  setcookie('translation', $jsonEncodedTranslation, time() + 86400, '/');
  $_COOKIE['translation'] = $jsonEncodedTranslation;
} elseif(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
  require_once($_GET['lang'].'.php'); // this looks evil btw
  $jsonEncodedTranslation = json_encode($translation);

  setcookie('translation', $jsonEncodedTranslation, time() + 86400, '/');
  $_COOKIE['translation'] = $jsonEncodedTranslation;
}

$decode = json_decode($_COOKIE['translation']);

echo $decode->home->title;
```

On a side note, this looks like a poor implementation. Most websites will include a translation file on every page, and that's totally fine because that's probably the fastest solution. You, on the other side, are encode/decoding on every page and forcing the client to send massive http headers (Cookie) on each request.